# An unexcepted result using boost::dynamic_bitset::to_ulong()

Tags: c++, boost

When I tried to use dynamic_bitset::to_ulong() to convert a binary to decimal number, a weird thing happened. My original number is 1010101,which is 85 in decimal. However, the following code prints 55 instead. I can't figure it out. My compiler is MingW.

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> db(10,BOOST_BINARY(1010101));
cout<<db.to_ulong()<<endl;  //should be 85.
```

Comment: @KerrekSB Err...Is it a joke? Don't quite get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

85 in decimal is 0x55 in hexadecimal. Check your iostream flags.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::dec << n << std::endl;  // formats as decimal
```